# How can I set a text widget to bottom-align in SWT?

Tags: java, swt

I'm working on an app in Java using SWT, and I have a text box where I want the text within to align to the bottom of the text box rather than the top. How can I do this?

I use this line to create the text widget:

```
txtTest = new Text(composite, SWT.MULTI | SWT.BOTTOM | SWT.WRAP | SWT.V_SCROLL);
```

But the text still aligns to the top of the box. I researched some and found that there are three style bits for alignment in `swt.widgets.Text`, `SWT.CENTER`, `SWT.LEFT`, and `SWT.RIGHT`, but no style bit for bottom alignment. Is there another way for me to align the text to the bottom?

Comment: The only alignment styles are LEFT, CENTER, RIGHT.  TOP is not a vaild style for Text. I don't believe there is any support for this in Text.

Comment: @greg-449 Woops, my mistake. You're right, edited.